# Error message when starting terminal. [zsh]

Tags: zsh, rbenv

When I start my terminal I get this message:

```
/usr/lib/rbenv/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash:16: command not found: complete
~ %
```

Everything else seems normal. I don't get the message when I run tmux, only when I start a new terminal.

Here's my ~/.zshrc file:

```
# load custom executable functions
for function in ~/.zsh/functions/*; do
  source $function
done

# extra files in ~/.zsh/configs/pre , ~/.zsh/configs , and ~/.zsh/configs/post
# these are loaded first, second, and third, respectively.
_load_settings() {
  _dir="$1"
  if [ -d "$_dir" ]; then
    if [ -d "$_dir/pre" ]; then
      for config in "$_dir"/pre/**/*(N-.); do
        . $config
      done
    fi

    for config in "$_dir"/**/*(N-.); do
      case "$config" in
        "$_dir"/pre/*)
          :
          ;;
        "$_dir"/post/*)
          :
          ;;
        *)
          if [ -f $config ]; then
            . $config
          fi
          ;;
      esac
    done

    if [ -d "$_dir/post" ]; then
      for config in "$_dir"/post/**/*(N-.); do
        . $config
      done
    fi
  fi
}
_load_settings "$HOME/.zsh/configs"

# aliases
[[ -f ~/.aliases ]] && source ~/.aliases
alias sz='source ~/.zshrc'

# Local config
[[ -f ~/.zshrc.local ]] && source ~/.zshrc.local

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

# rbenv config
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

What is causing this and how can I get rid of it? I can call up my version of Ruby successfully and I've run `rbenv init` and `rbenv rehash` already.

```
rbenv version
2.3.0 (set by /home/drempel/.rbenv/version)

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: `complete` is a _Bash_ builtin related to programmable completion; Zsh doesn't have it. Sounds like Zsh is evaluating something that was written for Bash.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that helps! I've found my issue is not rbenv. Although my exact issue is described and fixed [https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/487](here) it unfortunately doesn't work for my specific case. I started removing sections one at a time and saving my ~/.zsh file until the error stopped appearing and I narrowed the issue down to the **_load_settings() {...}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue posted on the [github page for rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/487) regarding the rbenv init script causing issues with zsh users. This was fixed in a later version. The answer there was to change `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"`. I did this but it did not clear the error message. After reading my ~/.zshrc file closer I realized it was loading files from ~/.zsh/configs.

In ~/.zsh/configs/post/path.zsh there was another rbenv init config:

```
# ensure dotfiles bin directory is loaded first
PATH="$HOME/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

# load rbenv if available
if command -v rbenv >/dev/null; then
  eval "$(rbenv init - --no-rehash)"
fi

# mkdir .git/safe in the root of repositories you trust
PATH=".git/safe/../../bin:$PATH"

export -U PATH
```

I changed the line `eval "$(rbenv init - --no-rehash)"` to reflect `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh --no-rehash)"` and this resolved my issue.

Comment: This gave me a hint. In my case I had this expression `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in `~/.zprofile` and also in `.zshrc`. Removing it from `.zprofile` seems to have fixed the issue. I'm on an M1 Pro FYI Monterey.